# Connect, repetitively, nodes based at their euclidean distance in omnet++

Tags: connection, nodes, omnet++

I have created a random topology in ned file. In that topology, every node has the same radian connection distance. I want to make connections for every node that is in the rc distance.

This is as far I have get:

```
network ranTop
{
    parameters:
        int n = 100;
        int rc = 5;
        volatile int posX = intuniform (0,100);
        volatile int posY = intuniform (0,100);

    submodules:
        node[n] : Node {
            parameters:
                @display("p=$posX,$posY");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have (non volatile!) `posX`, `posY` parameter for **each** node and then create a loop over all possible connections and connect the nodes **only** if the distance is less than `range`. You can access the node parameters in the loop and in the if condition too:

```
simple MeshNode extends Node
{
    parameters:
        int posX = default(intuniform(0,100));
        int posY = default(intuniform(0,100));

        @display("i=misc/node_vs;p=$posX,$posY");
    gates:
        inout g[];
}


//
// A network of nodes randomly placed where nodes 
// closer than 'range' are connected.
//
network MeshNetwork
{
    parameters:
        int num @prompt("Number of nodes") = default(100);
        int range = 15;  // nodes closer than this should be connected

    submodules:
        node[num] : MeshNode;

    connections allowunconnected:
        for i=0..(num-2), for j=(i+1)..(num-1) {
            node[i].g++ <--> node[j].g++ if pow(node[i].posX-node[j].posX, 2)+pow(node[i].posY-node[j].posY, 2) < range*range;
        }
}
```