# How can I get cTopology in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to get the list of neighbor addresses (nodes that are in transmission range). I found this code on omnet++ manual, but when I compile, I get the error of no member named 'extractByModuleType' in 'cTopology', i did go back to the class cTopology, and the function 'extractByModuleType()' does not exist. I tried other functions but I did not succeed. Please, if someone knows how to access cTopology answer my question.

Best regards;

```
cTopology topo;
topo.extractByModuleType("Host", nullptr);
for (int i = 0; i < topo.getNumNodes(); i++) {
  cTopology::Node *node = topo.getNode(i);
  EV << "Node i=" << i << " is " << node->getModule()->getFullPath() << endl;
  EV << " It has " << node->getNumOutLinks() << " conns to other nodes\n";
  EV << " and " << node->getNumInLinks() << " conns from other nodes\n";

  EV << " Connections to other modules are:\n";
  for (int j = 0; j < node->getNumOutLinks(); j++) {
    cTopology::Node *neighbour = node->getLinkOut(j)->getRemoteNode();
    cGate *gate = node->getLinkOut(j)->getLocalGate();
    EV << " " << neighbour->getModule()->getFullPath()
       << " through gate " << gate->getFullName() << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be

```
topo.extractByNedTypeName("Host");
```

according to the documentation.

Additionally, you indicate that you want to get the list of the nodes in 'transmission range'. So presumably, you have a wireless network where there are **no** connections between the nodes. cTopology discovers topology based on the connections and a wireless network does not have any, so you will not get meaningful results anyway.

Unless your nodes are not moving and you actually create a connection between neighboring nodes. This SO answer my give you help, how to do that: [Connect, repetitively, nodes based at their euclidean distance in omnet++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893912/connect-repetitively-nodes-based-at-their-euclidean-distance-in-omnet)

If you do connect them, then you just have to iterate through all your connections to reach the neighbor nodes and you will not need any cTopology magic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I understand that I cannot get neighbor addresses using cTopology since I have a wireless sensor network. You propose a solution but in which nodes are not moving. Could you please provide a solution to get the list of neighbors in the case of a mobile wireless sensor network.

Comment: You are welcome. If you have additional questions, please formulate it as a separate question. As a policy on Stack Overflow, you should not ask a different question in the comment section. The reason is that the whole discussion would get unstructured. Also, if an answer is acceptable for the given question, you should signal and accept it so other users would see it, too.